# Are these circles orthogonal?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let $a$ be any complex number with $|a|>1.$ Then how can I show that circles $$|z|=1, \,\,\,\,\,\,|z-a|=\sqrt{|a|^2-1}$$ are orthogonal.
One method is convert this problem in to Cartesian co-ordinates, then it becomes to show circles $$x^2+y^2=1, \,\,\,\,\,\,(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=p^2+q^2-1$$ are orthogonal for any $p^2+q^2>1.$

But I would like to see a proof of above fact only using the properties of complex numbers.
           Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without loss of generality we can assume $a > 1$ and $a$ is real. suppose $z = e^{it}$ is on both circles. then $t$ satisfies 
$$ e^{it} = a + \sqrt{a^2 - 1}e^{is}$$  for some $s.$

equating the real and imaginary parts, we get $$\cos t = a + \sqrt{a^2 - 1}\cos s, \sin t = \sqrt{a^2 - 1}\sin s $$ 
$$1 = \cos^2t + \sin^2 t = a^2 + 2a\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\cos s + (a^2-1)\cos^2 s + (a^2-1)\sin^2 s \\
= (2a^2-1)+2a\sqrt{a^2-1}\cos s  $$ which gives us 
$$a \cos s + \sqrt{a^2 - 1} = 0 \tag 1$$
we will compute 
$$\cos(s-t) = \cos s \cos t + \sin s \sin t  = [a+\sqrt{a^2 - 1}\cos s]\cos s + \sqrt{a^2 - 1}\sin^2 s = a \cos s + \sqrt{a^2 - 1} = 0 \text{ by } (1)$$

therefore $$ s - t = \pm \pi/2$$ and the two circles intersect at right angles.

Answer (score 3):

Two circles with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ and $d$ apart are orthogonal if $r_1^2 + r_2^2 = d^2$.

Simply plug in the values for $r_1, r_2$ and $d$.

Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalCircles.html

(PS: the above relation follows immediately from the Pythagorean theorem)

Comment: does it use complex numbers as asked by the op.

Comment: @abel: well, you can always prove the above relation using complex numbers..